# Virtual Hosts not working in Ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtualhost

I just migrated to `Ubuntu 14.04` and I installed `LAMP Stack` following [this](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-lamp-on-ubuntu) tutorial.
Now I have setup the virtual host by doing

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

and added following in the file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@dev.bridgessuservices
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/bridgessuservices
   ServerName dev.bridgessuservices
   ServerAlias dev.bridgessuservices
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and then adding the following line in `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1   dev.bridgessuservices
```

Now when I go to dev.bridgessuservices it is fine but inner URLs show me 404 like if I go to dev.bridgessuservices/login, it will show me 404

Comment: I suggest you take a look into your http servers error log file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Apache *mod-rewrite* module is not enabled. So please enable it and recheck again.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

For detail information about enabling please refer https://askubuntu.com/questions/48362/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-in-apache

Comment: What about AllowOverride settings in this case? Because it could be forbidden to re-define settings.